# Epub 2.0.1 validator error: "Error while parsing file: element "img" missing required attributes "alt" and "src"."

Tags: src, epub

I have tried six ways from Sunday to fix this.
Running through Calibre doesn't generate the same error.
Running through Sigil doesn't generator the error.
This is converted from a word .docx file with several images in the doc.

I have added alt text to the images withing Word so I wouldn't think the "alt" error would be an issue.
However the "src" error is beyond me. I know barely anything about epub file formats.

Comment: Can you describe how you converted the Word document to EPUB? And how you added "alt" text in Word? Those specifics would help someone to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I figured out the issue. The online word to epub converter I used was causing the errors. Once I installed the word2epub add-on to Word, I no longer had any issues.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. It's good practice to provide the answer that worked for you to help anyone else having the same question. On SO, a comment doesn't qualify as an answer.